# Automatic Login with spring security rest after user registration

Tags: grails, spring-security, spring-security-rest

I am developing an application using the react profile of grails and spring security rest for authentication. Please how can I automatically log a user in (get the response I would get when a user logs in) after the user registers. Is there a way to redirect to the login endpoint with the username and password after the user is successfully signed up?

Comment: non rest - you would log user in then refresh page. REST requires access token to be sent per transaction to backend. In effect the best way of doing something like this would be to set up a true/false trigger where by when a user signs up via rest the backend fires back succeeded or not or perhaps with errors but anyhow once you know you have success you would simply route through their current username/pass that you still have that they signed up with in segment of code doing rest signup so now call the auth function with user password like they would if they came back to login.